# How to detect double click on JSP

Tags: java, jsp

how can I make my jsp page detect a double click on the submit button. I am trying to do a simple print out message to check if a user has double clicked the submit button.
something like :

```
 <%***if user double clicks submit{
     System.out.println("doubleClick");` 
 }***%>
```

-Newbie trying to learn java programming.

Comment: you can do this by using jquery, why are you not trying it?

Comment: You don't want to use Java for this.  You want to use Javascript for this instead.  Although, depending on what your application actually *does* on a double-click, there are things you'll need to guard against on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Believe me you are not looking for **Java**

You can simply use `Javascript` function

```
ondblclick="myFunction()"
```

Or you can use Jquery for this:

```
$( "#target" ).dblclick(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .dblclick() called." );
});
```

## [Details](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ondblclick` attribute in your button element.E.g-

```
<input id="searchId" type="button" ondblclick="doubleFunc()" 
        name="submit">
```

Make sure you also handle the submit event in your script.